Keras: EarlyStopping use validation loss of untrained network instead of Inf
I have implemented early stopping with "ModelCheckpoint". The goal is to select the best trained model version and return the belonging epoch number.
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=earlyStoppingEpochs, restore_best_weights=False) 
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint.weights.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath, save_weights_only=True, monitor="val_loss", mode="min", save_best_only=True, verbose=verbose)
history = model.fit(Train_Data, Train_Label, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(Val_Data, Val_Label), verbose=verbose, callbacks=[early_stopping, checkpoint])
hist = model.history.history['val_loss']
finalEpochs = np.argmin(hist) + 1 
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)

Everything works. The only point that still bothers me is that the validation loss of the untrained model is not taken into account. Instead, the initial loss is set to Inf.
"Epoch 1: val_loss improved from **inf **to 2.35898, saving model to /tmp/checkpoint.weights.h5"
In my application, however, it is possible that even the first training epoch leads to a deterioration in the validation loss. Then it should return the untrained model as the best model and the ideal epoch number of 0.
Do you know if it is possible to adjust the behavior so that it does not use inf at the beginning of EarlyStopping, but the validation loss of the untrained model?

You can manually evaluate the model before training begins and set this as the baseline for early stopping. Here is how you can adjust your code:

Evaluate the untrained model on the validation set to get the initial validation loss.
Modify the EarlyStopping callback to use this initial validation loss as the baseline.

Example:
initial_val_loss = model.evaluate(Val_Data, Val_Label, verbose=0)

class CustomEarlyStopping(EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, initial_val_loss, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial_val_loss = initial_val_loss
        self.best = initial_val_loss

Hope this will help.

Thank you very much. Sounds promising. Then I just have to write something like finalEpochs = np.argmin([initial_val_loss , hist]).  If during the first epoch the loss gets worse, will model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath) automatically return the model before the first epoch?

I have tried your code now, however it doesn't seem to work. I have tried:

startLoss = 0.00001
early_stopping = CustomEarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=earlyStoppingEpochs, restore_best_weights=False, initial_val_loss=startLoss) And I get:
Epoch 1: val_loss improved from inf to 0.30686
Epoch 2: val_loss improved from 0.30686 to 0.23336

You had to do an additional editing in the class:
if self.wait >= self.patience and epoch > 0: CHANGE TO
if self.wait >= self.patience and epoch >= 0:
Now it works, thank you very much!

In Keras, according to this doc her:
https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/
You can actually specify the parameter  start_from_epoch=0 (it's 0 by default). In order to avoid the -inf, maybe you could start after a few epochs (2 for example); otherwise you will need to implement your own custom callback to achieve what you want.
Here is a full example tested with the latest keras==3.4.1
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Custom EarlyStoppingCallback class definition
class CustomEarlyStoppingCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, patience=0, min_delta=0, initial_best=float('inf')):
        super(CustomEarlyStoppingCallback, self).__init__()
        self.patience = patience
        self.min_delta = min_delta
        self.best_weights = None
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        self.best = initial_best

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        # self.best = self.best (already set during initialization)
        self.best_weights = None

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_loss = logs.get("val_loss")
        if current_loss is None:
            return
        
        if current_loss < self.best - self.min_delta:
            self.best = current_loss
            self.wait = 0
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print(f'Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch: {self.stopped_epoch - self.patience + 1}')

# Load and prepare the MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = mnist.load_data()

# Normalize the data
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
x_val = x_val.astype('float32') / 255.0

# One-hot encode the labels
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val, 10)

# Create a simple model
model = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
custom_early_stopping = CustomEarlyStoppingCallback(patience=3, min_delta=0.001, initial_best=2.64)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[custom_early_stopping])


Thank you for your answer. If I understand it correctly, I can use this setting to specify that it should not perform EarlySopping in the first n epochs. Unfortunately, if that is the case, it would not solve my problem. I would like it already to check the EarlyStopping from epoch 0 to epoch 1.

I'm afraid that, otherwise, you will need to implement your own custom callback to achieve what you want.

I updated the answer with an example you can start with :D

Thank you very much for your comment. This is the "cleanest" solution.

Can I add callbacks=[early_stopping, checkpoint] to get the best model? That is, if early_stopping stops after the first epoch because the untrained model is the best, does checkpoint return the untrained model?
